# Connecting to Oracle SDE using QGis 2.18 only seeing MDSYS

Tags: qgis, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

I am trying to add a layer using the Oracle connection in QGIS. I can connect when I test the connection. But what is returned is only the MDSYS owner (schema) and tables. There is one schema that I am expecting to see but it's not being returned. In other tools I can see the schema, but in QGIS I cannot. I've tried all different variations and checked "also list tables with no geometry." Which I wouldn't want to use because I am trying to grab a spatial table(s) under a schema. I'm wondering if the problem is that I am using Oracle SDE for the spatial tables... Any ideas on how I can return more schemas through this connection tool in QGIS?

Comment: I figured this out. I let the scan run after selecting "also list tables with no geometry." For some reason the SDE tables are being seen as having no geometry. But the schema that I was looking for was found. Note the scan took a long time.

Comment: QGIS can't read the proprietary SDE geometry.  You can change your Oracle ArcSDE to save geometry as SDO rather than SDE in the database and then you would be able to view it in QGIS.  There are some dbtune keywords you need to change - ```SDO_GEOMETRY``` - and then export the existing tables and import as new feature classes to make the change.

Comment: Thanks for your feed back. I have this figured out now. In case anyone else runs into this issue. Create a feature class and on the last panel choose to use configuration keywords instead of default, and then select SDO_GEOMETRY. Grant the account that you are using in QGIS to connect select rights. Then in QGIS select only look in metadata table, only existing geometry types, include additional geometry attributes. Save this connection and then it can be shared with others for easy use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this figured out now. In case anyone else runs into this issue. Create a feature class and on the last panel choose to use configuration keywords instead of default, and then select SDO_GEOMETRY. Grant the account that you are using in QGIS to connect select rights. Then in QGIS select only look in metadata table, only existing geometry types, include additional geometry attributes. Save this connection and then it can be shared with others for easy use.